# Unity. Событие на зажатой UI кнопке

Tags: c#, unity3d

Пытался сделать событие когда UI кнопка зажата, но всё безрезультатно.

Вот код:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.EventSystems;
public class turnleft : MonoBehaviour, IPointerDownHandler 
{

public void OnPointerDown(PointerEventData data)
{
    player.transform.localScale = new Vector3(-0.1f,0.1f,0.1f);
    player.transform.Translate(5 * Time.deltaTime, 0, 0);
} 
}
```

При попытки повесить этот метод на кнопку UI на событие onClick(), он просто не отображался.
Существует ли какой нибудь способ создания события на зажатую UI кнопку, например как на зажатую кнопку с клавиатуры?

```
if(Input.GetKey(KeyCode.A))
{
    Do something....
}
```

Comment: OnPointerDown работает не так, не вместе с компонентом Button, не OnClick(). Если уж используете, то почитайте хотя бы, как он используется. Зажатая кнопка - это значит УЖЕ нажата, но еще НЕ отпущена. Удачи

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`IPointerDownHandler` это интерфейс `EventSystem` - т.е. вам нужно повесить класс с этим интерфейсом на какой-нибудь объект с коллайдером (или RectTransform-ом) и когда кто-нибудь нажмёт на этот объект (именно нажмёт, но ещё не отпустит кнопку) - вызов метода произойдёт автоматически.

Соответственно вам нужно повесить ваш скрипт turnleft на нужную вам кнопку, назначать метод никуда не надо. Ещё вам нужно реализовать `IPointerUpHandler`, чтобы отслеживать момент, когда кнопку отпустят.

Теперь в методе `OnPointerDown` вы можете узнать, что кнопку нажали. После этого начинайте в методе `Update` вести отсчёт, как долго кнопка нажата. В методе интерфейса  `IPointerUpHandler` прекращайте ваш отсчёт.

Выглядеть будет примерно вот так:

```
public class turnleft : MonoBehaviour, IPointerDownHandler, IPointerUpHandler  
{
    [SerializeField]
    private float _activationDelay;

    private bool _onDown;
    private float _timeLeft;

    public void OnPointerDown(PointerEventData data)
    {
        _onDown = true;
    } 

    public void OnPointerUp(PointerEventData data)
    {
        _timeLeft = 0;
        _onDown = false;
    } 

    public void Update()
    {
        if (_onDown) 
        {
            _timeLeft += Time.deltaTime;
            if (_timeLeft >= _activationDelay)
            {
               _timeLeft = 0;
               _onDown = false;
               //Do something....
            }
        }
    }
}
```